# hour not change when minute going down/up with timepicker?

Tags: javascript, timepicker, bootstrap-timepicker

is that posible to lock hour when minute going down/up with bootstrap-timepicker heres my js

```
$('.bootstrap-timepicker').timepicker();
```

this is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ankit47/05z1uqxL/)

Bootstrap-timepicker

http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

Comment: oh im sorry im gonna edit my question